# To BEGIN or not to BEGIN

Tags: ruby

*(Crossposting note: This question has already been asked at [Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6879358), but did not get any answer so far)*

For a project (which consists of several independent Ruby programs), I wanted to provide an easy way to enable warnings, but not necessarily force it to be used in every single application. I ended up with a file `warnings.rb`, which has the following:

```
BEGIN { $VERBOSE = true }
```

To enable warnings in an application, one can either

```
require 'warnings'
```

or run the application using

```
ruby -r warnings .....
```

One might argue that the latter could also be achieved by running the
program using `ruby -w`, but `warnings.rb` also provides other stuff related to this topic.

This solution works to our satisfaction, but the `BEGIN` block is unnecessary. The only case I could come of would be  when someone else runs code in a `BEGIN` block which, when executed, would cause warnings.

This is a pretty exotic situation, so I think I can remove the `BEGIN` block without risking any harm, but I'm not absolutely sure. Am I right with this?

Comment: People invented configuration files to avoid such an ugliness.

Comment: I don't think this is the point. While I certainly don't want to put the verbosity setting into a general configuration file, even if you do it, you will have to decide there too whether the verbosity needs to be set in a BEGIN block (to guarantee that it is seen "early" enough) or not. Actually, a configuration file in Ruby - if done properly - is nothing else than a piece of Ruby code which will be required at some point (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Well, yes; what I meant, one might put the setting somewhere, provide a `Warning`/`Logger` class/module that is called like `Warning.puts "blah"` _and make this `puts` method to **lazily** retrieve the setting from the file when needed_.

Comment: Answering the exact question stated: the whole problem looks to me as “is `set_param` name clean enough, or should I be more explicit and use `set_parameter`?”—That said, the only correct answer on it is “who cares!”. But if you are still curious, yes, you are right, one might safely remove `BEGIN` block there.

Comment: @mudasobwa : Perhaps you misunderstand the intent of the warnings module (or I misunderstood your advice). I'm not going to write **any** warnings. `$verbose` instructs Ruby to issue warnings. This happens for example, when I `require` a file and there is an assignment to a variable, but the variable is not used a second time: If Ruby has seen my *warnings.rb* before, it will write a warning message to stderr. Hence I want to make sure that this setting is seen before anything else is executed.